# Drawing Text On Window

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I want to make chat application and for the first step, I need to know which API there is to use to display text in lines and also erase if needed. thanks!

Comment: If you are going to use only the pure win32 API to write an app, you need to know much. much more than that, I'm afraid. And the answer will (and has) fill a book.

Comment: did you mean just to display and erase the text i gonna need a bunch of functions or to write the whole application?

Comment: The former - you need to create a window, you need a message loop, you need to understand painting and invalidation etc. etc.

Comment: Dave17, any reason why you're not making your life easier by choosing a less low-level-lib like WTL, MFC or Qt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Charles Petzold's classic book [Programming Windows](http://www.charlespetzold.com/pw5/index.html) is one of the best ways to learn the Win32 API.

Answer (score -2):

If you are just going to work with Windows, why not use something easier, like C# and WinForms or WPF?